# Short circuit assignment with default first value

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, conditional-operator

What I want to is something like the following:

```
let x=32
let y=x===32 ?: 7;
```

My real life example would be more like the following:

```
inlineFunction(parameterWithLongNameIAmTesting===20000?parameterWithLongNameIAmTesting:anotherLongNameVariable);
```

Basically short circuiting the ternary.  I want `y` to equal `x` if, and only if, `x` === 32.  In the case above the value assigned to `y` would be 32.  However if I had assigned `x` to equal 50 or anything else, then `y` would equal 7.

Is there a built-in way in javascript to do this?

Comment: `y = x === 32 ? x : 7;`

Comment: How do you define "elegant"? What is the objective measurement that will be used to determine if a solution is more or less "elegant"?

Comment: You'll obviously want `let y = (x === 32) * 25 + 7;` jk, jk

Comment: @MuhammadMehdi Please don't include the bare tags in the title. If you must incorporate the tag in the title, make them flow with the title, as with "... in JavaScript" or the like.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - perhaps my intention is more clear with my addendum.

Comment: @ChrisG - I would like to subscribe to your coding blog

Comment: It's still opinion based, and irrelevant. In the age of minifiers, trying to get things on one line is no longer necessary.

Comment: @ChrisG - I love it.

Answer (score 5):

You'd use `32` or `x` as the second operand:

```
let y = x === 32 ? x : 7;
```

Re:

> The reason why I am looking for this is that in the real life situation I am using, the actual expression would look like this:
>
> ```js
> inlineFunction(parameterWithLongNameIAmTesting===20000?parameterWithLongNameIAmTesting:anotherLongNameVariable);
> ```
>
> It just looks really messy that way.

If it's **just** the mess, you can format it more clearly (IMHO) ([SharedRory also makes this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69379891/157247)):

```js
inlineFunction(
    parameterWithLongNameIAmTesting === 20000
    ?   parameterWithLongNameIAmTesting
    :   anotherLongNameVariable
);
```

Or if you don't like the repeated long names, you can use a local const:

```
const x = parameterWithLongNameIAmTesting;
inlineFunction(x === 20000 ? x : anotherLongNameVariable);
```

> Is there a built-in way in javascript to do this?

Nothing other than the conditional operator above, or an `if`/`else`. You said in a comment you thought something had been added. You *might* be thinking of optional chaining (`let y = something?.prop;`) which short-circuits if `something` is `null` or `undefined`, resulting in `undefined` rather than the error `something.prop` would be. But that doesn't apply here.

Comment: Not elegant enough. :P

Comment: Its better to use x so you don't have to change the value twice

Comment: See my edit to the question and maybe it will be a little more clear why I am looking for an altenative.

Comment: @SharedRory - That was my feeling...so why did I end up with 32 in the answer?! Fixed it.

Comment: @dgo - I've added an edit.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Your edit is great.  I should probably edit my question.  For some reason, I thought this feature had been built into javascript in ESxxxx.  I guess not though.

Comment: @dgo - Yeah, there's nothing I can think of (and I did write a book on it :-D ).

Comment: @dgo - Ah! I think I know what you were thinking of -- optional chaining. I've added a note to the end of the answer. Doesn't apply here though I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder.  I knew that wasn't it, but I was hoping at the time that got introduced, this might of as well.  *c'est la vie*

Answer (score 2):

Since you added an example, its common to see the following in a lot of code because its easy to read and not all on one line.

```js
inlineFunction(
  parameterWithLongNameIAmTesting === 20000
    ? parameterWithLongNameIAmTesting
    : anotherLongNameVariable
);
```

Also formatters will usually do this too.

Comment: That's definitely better than what it looks like now.

Comment: Or just use a separate variable for the outcome of the ternary. Not like you pay by the line; a decent minifier will make that into 10 or 11 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, but you can use a function like

```
eq = (a, b) => a === b ? a : undefined
```

in a combination with the null coalescing operator. Example:

```js
eq = (a, b) => a === b ? a : undefined

test = 20000
defaultValue = 333

res = eq(test, 20000) ?? defaultValue
console.log(res)

test = 4444
defaultValue = 333

res = eq(test, 20000) ?? defaultValue
console.log(res)
```

As usual with functions, the advantage is that you can use them with arbitrary expressions, not just variables, for example:

```
return eq(computeChecksum(file), getStoredChecksum()) ?? '<failed>'
```

Comment: This is definitely clever.  For whatever reason, I thought there was a built in way to do this that got introduced in ESxxxx